# How can I say to lightly understand something? Does faintly understand work?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

I want to say something along these lines:

"With Coronavirus spreading globally, people are starting to faintly understand the situation that the slaves were going through every day ... the fear, the uncertainty, ... "

So, my question is, what word can I use to imply a little bit of understanding and not a deep one. thanks in advance and excuse my poor English please.

Comment: I would just use *dimly* instead of *faintly* there, but it may be better to recast the sentence to something like: "... people are starting to acquire the barest understanding of what the slaves were going through ..." Lots of ways to say this.

Comment: _Dimly_ is a good choice; it invokes the `Vision` metaphor for understanding. But why not avoid the adverb altogether and just say _are beginning to understand_? You can add _dimly_ for emphasis, but that's what it means anyway; you start out dim and get brighter, hopefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple options that work fairly well.

- somewhat
- vaguely
- partially
- kind of (or kinda)
- sort of (or sorta)

[Google's NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=faintly%20understand%2C%20partially%20understand%2C%20kind%20of%20understand%2C%20sort%20of%20understand%2C%20vaguely%20understand%2C%20somewhat%20understand&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfaintly%20understand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpartially%20understand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckind%20of%20understand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csort%20of%20understand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvaguely%20understand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csomewhat%20understand%3B%2Cc0) shows that faintly is less common than any of those.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's no really suitable single-word antonym for 'fully' in 'fully understand' here. 'Partially' is rather weak. 'Faintly' *is* better here, but I'd use:

With Coronavirus spreading globally, people are starting to understand, **in a small measure**, the situation that the slaves were going through every day....

Comment: I vaguely understand calculus.

Comment: Yes; I'd use 'vaguely' with that example.